# How do you click a page element (or cause the equivalent action) using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to click a tab on the following page using jQuery (or at least trigger the same functions as clicking does).  Here is what I tried:

```
jQuery('ul.gk_tab_ul-style1 li.first').next().click();
```

I need to click the middle tab ("Final Version").  I don't have a good way to identify the tab, other than it will always be the second tab.

How can I click the tab using jquery?

Page: http://www.fixoodle.com/fixes/899

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.eq(n)  starts from 0 and you can choose the 2nd tab  in the list by

```
$('ul.gk_tab_ul-style1 li').eq(1)
```

and click it by using trigger

```
    $('ul.gk_tab_ul-style1 li').eq(1).trigger('click');
```

hope this will help you. More on [.eq() here.](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: Thanks, the eq tip was great.  Much appreciated.